# Postman tests - Assert response is a valid XML

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

I would like to verify that the response of my webservice is a valid xml.
I know that it can be simply done for json responses using the following snippet:

```
    pm.response.to.be.json;
```

What about XML ?

```
pm.test("The body of the response is a valid XML", function () {
    pm.response.to.be.withBody;
    pm.response.to.be.xml; // ❓
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be multiple ways, here is the one.

Convert XML body to a JSON object using in built function [`xml2Json`](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_examples/#convert-xml-body-to-a-json-object). If the function returns a value, response valid, otherwise, it is invalid.

```
pm.test("The body of the response is a valid XML", function () {
     pm.expect(xml2Json(responseBody)).to.exist;
});
```